# Fragment shader mixing two cube textures based on alpha not working

Tags: three.js

I have a problem completely alluding me. I am trying to mix two cube textures together. But for some reason I cannot seem to mix one texture with the other based on the alpha. The function looks like this:

`vec4 baseColor = textureCube( tCube, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPosition.x, vWorldPosition.yz ) );`

`vec4 atmosphereColor = textureCube( tAtmosphere, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPosition.x, vWorldPosition.yz ) );`

`vec4 texelColor = mix( atmosphereColor, baseColor, atmosphereColor.a );`

`gl_FragColor = texelColor;`

All the materials concerned have depthWrite: true, depthTest: true and transparent: true. One is a texture with 6 images and the other is a WebGLRenderTarget. The WebGLRenderTarget is created with an alpha channel.

`format: THREE.RGBAFormat`

Individually they both work as expected. For example if I use `gl_FragColor = atmosphereColor;`, the alpha is visible. But as soon as I try to mix one with the other, no alpha is applied. So for example when I do this:

`gl_FragColor = vec4( baseColor.r, baseColor.g, baseColor.b, atmosphereColor.a );`

It still will not use the alpha variable provided (it just sets it to 1.0) - even though I know the value is present and varying as I just set gl_FragColor to atmosphereColor and could see it varying D:>

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the source of the problem. It was related to to the clearAlpha parameter of the renderer. This needed to be set to 0 instead of 1 for my case.